# How to run Spring batch job only after completion running job

Tags: spring-batch

I have a list of records to process via a spring batch job. Each record has millions of data points, I want to process each record one after another otherwise database will not handle the load.

Data will be like this:

> artworkList will contain 10 records and each artwork record will containt 30 million of data.

I am using spring batch with quartz schedular.

Comment: Do you have a single artworkList or many of them? If it's a single one having 10 records, then you can define a job per record (so 10 jobs in total) and run those jobs in sequence: either by calling them on the command line one after another (in a loop for instance), or by using a synchronous task executor in the JobLauncher (which is the default). Otherwise, please share how you would decompose this problem into units of work (which will be implemented as Spring Batch jobs).

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine for your comment. Yes I have all the artowork 10 records in a signle list. Currently I am using SimpleAsyncTaskExcecutor now I will change it to synchronous task executor in the JobLauncher. And currently I am using **@Async** annotation on the **runTask()** method. Do I need to remove this annotation with synchronous task executor ?

Comment: with an asynchronous task executor all jobs will run concurrently. If you really want them to run in sequence, you need a synchronous executor (the default SyncTaskExecutor should do it). In that case, you don't need the `@Async` annotation.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine . I will check with your suggested changes.